# How am I billed in Firestore for a whereEqualTo query?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

I have a collection of 100 elements. In this collection, only two elements have the field `available` set to true. If I use this query:

```
db.collection("elements").whereEqualTo("available", true);
```

I get 2 elements. Am I billed with 2 read operations or 100?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are billed a read for each document returned from the query that originated at the server (not read from local cache).

Comment: If your result set has two documents that originated at the server, then it stands to reason that you will be billed two reads.

Comment: Thanks again @Doug Stevenson!

Answer (score 4):

You are going to be billed for two reads.

You will find more details in this official video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6NegFl9p_sE&, in particular at 2 min 18 sec.

Comment: So it doesn't matter how many elements are in the collection, I'm billed only with two, correct?

Comment: @JohansBormman Yes. I would suggest you watch the video. Todd Kerpelman from Firebase explains it very well.

Comment: Thank you for your answer and video.